# Chef: no implicit conversion of String into Integer TypeError

Tags: ruby, search, chef-infra

I wrote a small Chef library that looks like this:

```
module Test
  module Search
    extend self

    def single_node(type, value)
      result = Chef::Search::Query.new.search(:node, "#{type}:#{value}",
                                              filter_result: {
                                                'name' => ['name']
                                              }).map { |n| n['name'] }.first
      return result
    end

  end
end
```

When running test code against it I get the following error:

```
TypeError
---------
no implicit conversion of String into Integer

         1:  module Test
         2:    module Search
         3:      extend self
         4:      def single_node(type, value)
         5:        result = Chef::Search::Query.new.search(:node, "#{type}:#{value}",
         6:                                                filter_result: {
         7:                                                  'name' => ['name']
         8>>                                               }).map { |n| n['name'] }.first
         9:        return result
        10:      end


        13:  end
        14:
```

After some playing around I found that the search contained this information:

```
[[{"name"=>"influxdb.example.org"}], 0, 1].
```

This seems odd as the search options used return something different when searching from within the Chef DSL.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. Why is the result different from what the Chef DSL's search would return? The format seems odd with the extra integers and the value I want is a Hash (correct) within an array (also correct I think) within an array. This same search within the DSL returns the first result correctly (a node name) without an error at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When executing the search in a recipe you're calling [the search method in recipe DSL](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/dsl/data_query.rb#L34-L47), which already iterate over the results before sending them back.

When you call `Chef::Sarch::Query.new.search`you're calling the [underlying method](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/search/query.rb#L83) out of the dsl helper and have to iterate over the results yourself if you don't pass a block to the method to work on the results.

You end up [here](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/search/query.rb#L110) which returns an array containing the query result array, along with the start and size of results (for pagination on UI).

So the final answer as already been given by @Oleander, call `first` before `map`, to call `map` in the result part of the return (first array entry) ignoring the pagination variables.

Or to get the same behavior as in the recipe DSL use Chef::DSL::DataQuery like this:

```
require 'chef/dsl/data_query'

module Test
  module Search
    extend self
    include Chef::DSL::DataQuery

    def single_node(type, value)
      result = search(:node, "#{type}:#{value}",
                             filter_result: {
                               'name' => ['name']
                             }).map { |n| n['name'] }.first
      return result
    end
  end
end
```

On the same idea to shorten your code:

```
require 'chef/dsl/data_query'

module Test
  module Search
    extend self
    include Chef::DSL::DataQuery

    def single_node(type, value)
      return search(:node, "#{type}:#{value}",
                             filter_result: {
                               'name' => ['name']
                             }).first['name']
    end
  end
end
```

Which return the first result too and get it's name, should be a little quicker as it does not have to 'subset' all entries but only the first one.

Answer (score 2):

If what you posted is your return value, then just run `first` on it and you're done.

```
result = Chef::Search::Query.new.search(:node, "#{type}:#{value}", filter_result: {
  'name' => ['name']
}).first.map { |n| n['name'] }.first
```